# $root is undefined on foreach loop when i try to make a nav-tab

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to make a foreach loop with knockout and i succeed, but i want the href to iterate in other observable variable, however it appears on the console "TypeError: $root is undefined"

This is what i have

```
var vm = function () {
    this.season = ko.observable(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]);
    this.ids = ko.observable(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
}; ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: season">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="html: $data, attr: { href: '#'+$root.ids}"></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: season">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" data-bind="attr: { 'id': $root.ids}">
        <h3 data-bind="text: $data"></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question, but I'm guessing you need to provide `applyBindings` with a view-model object instead of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create anchors with `href` set to `#a`, `#b` etc and corresponding `tab-pane` div's id to be `a`, `b` and so on.

First, you need to pass an object to `ko.applyBindings` not the function itself.

So, you can either use an object literal

```
var vm = {
    season: ko.observable(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]),
    ids: ko.observable(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

or

in your case, use the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator on the constructor function to create an object

```
var vm = function () {
    this.season = ko.observable(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]);
    this.ids = ko.observable(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
}; 
// new vm() creates an object with season and id keys
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Secondly, you are appending `ids` observable with `#` in every `href`. Instead, you can use [`$index`](http://note-2-using-index-parent-and-other-context-properties) to get the corresponding small letter for the current capital letter in context. `$index` refers to the index of the current `season` array item. Since both `ids` and `$index` are observables you need to use parenthesis to get their value like this: `$root.ids()[$index()]`

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var vm = function () {
    this.season = ko.observableArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]);
    this.ids = ko.observable(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
}; 

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: season">
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="text: $data, attr: { href: '#'+$root.ids()[$index()]}"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: season">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" data-bind="attr: { 'id': $root.ids()[$index()]}">
    <h3 data-bind="text: $data"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```